# Automate builds for Java RCP for deployment with JNLP

Tags: java, build-automation, rcp, jnlp

I've found many sources that talk about the automated Eclipse PDE process.  I feel these sources don't do a good job explaining what's going on.

I can create the deployable package, in a semi-manual process via the Feature Export.

The automated process requires knowledge of how the org.eclipse.pde.build scripts work.  I have gotten a build created, but not for JNLP.

Questions:

1. Has anyone ever deployed RCP through JNLP?
2. Were you able to automate the builds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't done this before, but I found [this site](http://i-proving.com/space/RCP+and+Java+Web+Start) on the web giving an explanation.